# SwiftUI: Spacer doesn't work at ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scrollview, vstack

How can I get space in VStack to pin the button at the bottom?

```
ScrollView {
        VStack() {
            Text("Title_1")
                .padding(.bottom, 35.0)
            Text("Title_2")
                .padding(.bottom, 32.0)
            Text("Title_3")
                .padding(.bottom, 27.0)
            
            Spacer()
            Button(action: { print("ACTION") }) {
                Text("OK")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                    
            }
            .frame(height: 35)
            .cornerRadius(8.0)
            .padding(.bottom, 25.0)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
```

[what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdrVK.png)

[what I want to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpES9.png)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `GeometryReader`

> A container view that defines its content as a function of its own size and coordinate space.
> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/geometryreader

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
    ScrollView {
        VStack() {
          -----
        }
        .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
    }
}
```

Doing so, the VStack is full-screen.

---

You may not neeed to use `ScrollView`, because you do not need to scroll to see its content.

```
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack() {
            Text("Title_1")
                .padding(.bottom, 35.0)
            Text("Title_2")
                .padding(.bottom, 32.0)
            Text("Title_3")
                .padding(.bottom, 27.0)
            
            Spacer()
            Button(action: { print("ACTION") }) {
                Text("OK")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                
            }
            .frame(height: 35)
            .cornerRadius(8.0)
            .padding(.bottom, 25.0)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
```

But if your content's height is more than the screen height, the `OK` button is at the bottom, regardless. Hence, you do not need to do anything.

Answer (score 39):

The **ScrollView** gives that **VStack** `infinite` possible height. That's why the spacers not working.

#### The Fix:

- Give the **VStack** a `minimumHeight` that’s the height of the **ScrollView** or **View**
- Also important to set the **scrollview's** `width` to be the **view's** `width`

```swift
GeometryReader { geometry in
    ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
        VStack {
        ...
        }
        .frame(minHeight: geometry.size.height)
    }.frame(width: geometry.size.width)
}
```

**THIS WAY THE CONTENT WILL BE ABLE TO LAYOUT BEYOND THE VIEW's HEIGHT IF NEEDED**

Comment: At a glance, this looks nice and works. Sadly, at least with iOS 15, because of this approach, the text views inside VStack can get compressed, resulting in the truncated text. To test: put several blocks of Text views inside the Stack, so it would be one screen height worth of content, some of the Text views would get compressed, some won't in my case.

Comment: @NeverwinterMoon i just checked and works for me now, maybe it was a bug that got fixed.

Comment: Unfortunately this has some weird behavior if it's inside of a NavigationView.

Comment: Doesn't work in iOS17

Answer (score -3):

Setting minHeight to screen height like other answers suggested works, but it brings issue where the ScrollView will no longer scroll beyond the screen height.

Proper solution is wrapping a VStack outside of the ScrollView.

For your case,

```
VStack {
    ScrollView {
        VStack() {
            Text("Title_1")
                .padding(.bottom, 35.0)
            Text("Title_2")
                .padding(.bottom, 32.0)
            Text("Title_3")
                .padding(.bottom, 27.0)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
    Spacer()
    Button(action: { print("ACTION") }) {
        Text("OK")
          .font(.title)
          .fontWeight(.semibold)
          .foregroundColor(Color.red)
    }
    .frame(height: 35)
    .cornerRadius(8.0)
    .padding(.bottom, 25.0)
}
```

Comment: It won't give your the best user experience